# Is the garbage collector running in a separate process?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Does the garbage collector start in a separate process?

For example:

1. If we try to measure process time taken by some piece of code and during this the garbage collector starts collecting, will it start on a new process or in the same process?
2. Is it working like the following?

   ```
   //Code (Process 1)
   --> Garbage Collector Run (Process 1)
   //Code (Process 1)
   ```

   Or like this?

   ```
   //Code (Process 1)
   --> Garbage Collector Run (Process 2)
   //Code (Process 1)
   ```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it runs in the same process, in the same thread which is performing an allocation, but I have no proof to support my statement. Just my common sense.

Comment: My bet - same process, since otherwise os would prevent it from managing another process memory.

Comment: Not sure because for me I think that it's run in different process https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx that's but need to be sure

Comment: Different process? It would have to be in the same process - but could be on a different thread http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps.aspx

Comment: Since a different process has its own virtual memory, running the GC in a separate process makes no sense.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The garbage collector runs the thread that triggered garbage collection, on the very same process. It stops all current thread, and executes itself. It doesn't start another process for sure, you would have seen that in Windows.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Before a garbage collection starts, all managed threads are suspended except for the thread that triggered the garbage collection.

(This applies to workstations only, as pointed out by [DrKoch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29208494/993547)). Servers have a background thread running for garbage collection.

If you search in the referenced documentation for "Concurrent garbage collection", you will the text "GC thread", which supporting this.

You can force to run garabage collection in a separate thread, if you want to. Put this in your `app.config`:

```xml
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <gcServer enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

(from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2873514/993547))

Also read [The .NET Framework 4.5 includes new garbage collector enhancements for client and server apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps.aspx), as suggested by [Adam Houldsworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358221/adam-houldsworth), about changes in the way the garbage collector works since .NET 4.5.

Comment: So Their is any way to know how much time is taken by the garbage collector during a process ?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Both. I found the config option already. Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickHofman their is any way to know if during a method the Garbage Collector was called or not like handling a signal ?

Comment: @Omega: Not sure. If you use a decent memory profiler, you will see it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes but i want handle it in codding like any script or method or event ?

Comment: No. You can't measure that.

Answer (score 9):

First there is a distinction between **process** and **thread**.
As pointed aout by @CodesInChaos each **process** has its own adress space, so running GC in a separate process makes no sense.

If we talk about **threads**:
there is a difference between "Workstation" and "Server". On a workstation it runs on one of the user threads:

> The collection occurs on the user thread that triggered the garbage collection

On a server it runs in separate, dedicated threads:

> The collection occurs on multiple dedicated threads that are running at THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST priority level.

If your machine is considered a "server" depends on configuration:

> <gcServer> element of the runtime configuration schema

See [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Can you add the correct URL to `Fundamentals of Garbage Collection`?

Comment: So Their is any way to know how much time is taken by the garbage collector during a process ?

Comment: It is my understanding, from the article you linked) that by default server GC is disabled (gcServer enabled is false). So you still need to enable it explicitly.

Comment: But if we are talking about Workstation GC